# how to create a new column in a dataframe based on conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column as NEGATIVE_AMT. The values inside the NEGATIVE_AMT columns lies between 0 to 72000.

```
NEGATIVE_AMT
0
1200
50000
22000
28000
 and so on ..
```

Now i want to create a new column in the dataframe as NEGATIVE_AMT_PERCENTILE and the values inside the column should be based on the below 4 conditions:

1. If the negative_amt is lesser than 25th percentile of the value then NEGATIVE_AMT_PERCENTILE = 25th percentile value.
2. If the negative_amt is lesser than 50th percentile of the value but greater than 25th percentile then NEGATIVE_AMT_PERCENTILE = 50th percentile value.
3. If the negative_amt is lesser than 75th percentile of the value but greater than 50th percentile then NEGATIVE_AMT_PERCENTILE = 75th percentile value.
4. If the negative_amt is greater than 75th percentile of the value then NEGATIVE_AMT_PERCENTILE = 75th percentile value.

i tried using np.where but there is some mistake in my code:
I tried doing

```
df['NEGATIVE_AMT_PERCENTILE) = np.where(df['NEGATIVE_AMT]< df['NEGATIVE_AMT'].quantile(0.25), df['NEGATIVE_AMT'].quantile(0.25),
np.where((df['NEGATIVE_AMT]< df['NEGATIVE_AMT'].quantile(0.50) & df['NEGATIVE_AMT] > df['NEGATIVE_AMT'].quantile(0.25), df['NEGATIVE_AMT'].quantile(0.50),
np.where((df['NEGATIVE_AMT]< df['NEGATIVE_AMT'].quantile(0.75) & df['NEGATIVE_AMT] > df['NEGATIVE_AMT'].quantile(0.50), df['NEGATIVE_AMT'].quantile(0.75),
np.where(df['NEGATIVE_AMT]> df['NEGATIVE_AMT'].quantile(0.75), df['NEGATIVE_AMT'].quantile(0.75))
```

if for example my 25th percentile is 150, 50th percentile is 2000, 75th percentile is 25000 and 100th percentile is 72000
Then my expected output should be

```
Expected Output

NEGATIVE_AMT| NEGATIVE_AMT_PERCENTILE
0           |       150
1200        |       2000
50000       |      25000
22000       |      25000
28000       |      25000
```

My code throws an error as "Invalid Syntax"
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why does >75th percentile get mapped to 75th percentile? #3 and #4 do the same thing.

Comment: What is the mistake in your code? Please provide *a sample* of your expected output, and how it differs from your actual output. Please also fix the code you've posted, as it is not currently valid Python syntax.

Comment: Please also clarify: "the negative_amt is lesser than 25th percentile of **the value**", what value?

Comment: any value which is lesser than the 25th percentile of the value should be replaced with 25th percentile value. in my data the 25th percentile value is 150 so any value which is lesser than 150 should be replaced with 150 .

Comment: yes the 3rd and the 4th condition should do the same thing.

Comment: `numpy.select` is probably more useful than `numpy.where` here

Comment: "yes the 3rd and the 4th condition should do the same thing" then why bother with separate conditions? Just do "if greater than 50th percentile, make value 75th percentile".

Comment: can someone help me with the code. My code throws an error

Comment: Please post your error, and please also review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The error states "invalid syntax"

Comment: @kaaviya was your question answered? If so, please the answer as accepted so that your post is removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this achieves what you're after, but since you did not provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I can't confirm.

```py
import numpy as np

quantiles = df.quantile([0.25, 0.5, 0.75]).values.reshape(3,)
q1, q2, q3 = quantiles

conditions = [df.NEGATIVE_AMT < q1, df.NEGATIVE_AMT.between(q1, q2), df.NEGATIVE_AMT > q2]

output = np.select(conditions, quantiles)
```

Note that in your question you do not specify what should be done at the boundaries of these thresholds. The `df.NEGATIVE_AMT.between(q1, q2)` is inclusive of both endpoints, so your conditions are equivalent to:

```
x < q1 -> q1

q1 <= x <= q2 -> q2

x > q2 -> q3
```